# Add custom category templates to magento

Tags: magento, templates

I am building a webshop that contains the products for over 25 different shops. For every shop we have a similar but slightly different layout for the homepage. I want to add additional templates to use for every shops sub homepage.  I found that i can add templates to local.xml . However I can only get it to work for one template.. What is the correct way to add multiple templates to local.xml ?

```
    <page>
        <layouts>
            <homepage>
                <label>Home Page</label>
                <template>page/1column-home.phtml</template>
            </homepage>
        </layouts>
    </page>
```

Many thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have 2 Solutions :-

- To add Layout pages in the select menu as you have to add the XML in Module ( config.xml ) not in theme layout ( local.xml )

So to achieve this create Custom Module and in config.xml

```
  <global>
    .......  
      <page>
        <layouts>
            <custom_layout_page >
                <label>custom_layout_page</label>
                <template>page/custom_layout_page.phtml</template>
                <layout_handle>custom_layout_page</layout_handle>
            </custom_layout_page>
        </layouts>
    </page>
  .......
</global>
```

See Screen below :

[image: category]

### OR:

- You can create the template phtml file in your theme, for example in folder

> > > page/category_custom_template.phtml

Then you can use the layout update for the category you want to assign this file as layout page or template root

Like the screen shot below :

[image: category]

Comment: Hey thx for your anwser! However it doesn't show the custom layout file  if I only add a new file... I have to add it to local.xml as mentioned above. I can only get one template to work...

Comment: Hmmm, its not exactly what i was looking for but it seems to work! Very strange I tried this before.. I wil mark your awnser correct shortly! Thx again

Comment: I have added the other solution you meant above.